# In Three.js, how to translate a Vector3?

Tags: vector, three.js

I have created a `Vector3()` called `ori`, and I have populated its coordinates x, y and z. How, now, do I translate this vector, say along axis z, of the indicated value?

I tried this:

```
 ori.translateZ( - 100);
```

This gets me an error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'translateZ' of undefined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to translate by a single axis, it's as simple as adding the translation value:

```
ori.z += -100;
```

If you want to translate by a vector, it's again very simple:

```
var trans = new THREE.Vector3(-100,-200,-300);
ori.add(trans);
```

Answer (score 5):

Matey gave the answer you need, but didn't tell you why your method didn't work. ori is a Vector3 and not a Object3D. *translateZ()* is a method of the Object3D class, but not a method of the Vector3 class.  If the position member of an Object3D class had been set to equal ori (position is a Vector3) then translateZ on that Object3D instance would have worked.

Your understanding is correct. The answer juagicre gave would only change the z value to-100

Answer (score 0):

```
ori.setZ(-100);
```

[Vector3 documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3)

Comment: As far as I understand, this instruction modifies the z coordinates, it does not make a translation of the amount given, so it does not what I want.

Comment: you were talking about vector, not about object3d, you cannot translate a vector, but an object, so here is the solution for your question ;)