# In three.js how to retrieve the position of an object?

Tags: three.js

I have created an object, a cone, and have located it, orientated it, and then translated it along its axis z. Well, now I want to retrieve its position in x, y and z and store the information in an array for later use.

```
var cone = new THREE.Mesh(coneGeometry, coneMaterial);
var φ =   wup[iter].Latitude*Math.PI/180;
var λ = - wup[iter].Longitude*Math.PI/180;
//φ phi lat     λ lambda lon
cone.position.set (
      Math.cos(λ) * 90 * Math.cos(φ),
      Math.sin(φ) * 90,
      Math.sin(λ) * 90 * Math.cos(φ)
);
cone.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0) );
cone.translateZ( - earthRadius * réduc);
wup[iter].x  =  cone.x;
wup[iter].y  =  cone.y;
wup[iter].z  =  cone.z; /
```

The problem is that `cone.x` does not contain anything.

Comment: `cone.position.x` … Position is a vector…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687901/philipp)'s indication, and on [the reply to a neighboring question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517483/in-three-js-how-to-translate-a-vector3), here is the code that worked:

```
wup[iter].x  =  cone.position.x;
wup[iter].y  =  cone.position.y;
wup[iter].z  =  cone.position.z;
```

`cone`, as a geometry, has a vector called `position` associated to it with coordinates. Consequently, retrieving the coordinates of the geometry implies calling the coordinates of its vector `position`.